# WatiN wait for java script execution completed before click link (IE)

Tags: automation, watin

i have this page displaying statement every 2 second (using javascript), at the end of it there is a link which the user can click.

with IE it will click the link before javascript generated statement is completed.
when i use Link.Click()

(with Firefox it will throw exception, which is fine with me)

is there a way to wait for javascript execution to complete before link gets clicked (IE)?

TIA

EDITED
// the code, pretty simple seaching for link that startwith //"Continue seaching" in the browser then click

```
if (ln.Text.StartsWith("Continue searching", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
{
  ln.Click();
}
```

Thx

Comment: Can you please clarify? What is `Link.Click()`? And you should probably add the code to the question.

Comment: You should post your code too.

Comment: This is not a javascript issue, this looks like C# used serverside, and the Link.Click is a serverside event, not a client side event.

Comment: @Sean Kinsey: This question is tagged improperly, but I don't have rep to retag. This should be tagged `WatiN` in first place. Maybe even `C#`. `WatiN` is a `C#` library for browser automation (you can google it). And that's why I used `Thread.Sleep` in my answer.

Comment: @Sean Kinsey: Well, you deleted the appropriate tag by yourself :/

Answer (score 0):

return false from the function "Link.Click" then the default behaviour will be disregarded.

Comment: thx for the reply,
unfortunately the link.Click is successful if run using IE
(Firefox will throw exception), while the javascript still executing and page is still scrolling has not shown the link yet.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the link is already loaded, but javascript will attach some events to it a little bit later, right? Could you just wait a little bit using `Thread.Sleep(500)`? Or maybe you can find out what is going on after execution of javascript code. You will have to find out how js on that page works, but maybe js is adding some sort of class or something similar to that link so you could wait in active loop with a little bit of `Thread.Sleep` until js do its job.

Comment: thx,

that's what im doing now currently, just wondering whether there is a neater way of doing this.

(btw, no event attached to the link, just want to click the link after the javascript stopped executing not when it still executing)

thx

Comment: Yeah, but maybe the page itself is attaching some kind of event or modifying the page DOM, so you could just wait for that to happened. That's exactly what WatiN do when its waiting for 'complete' or 'until something' - WatiN is actively waiting in `while` loop. See `TryFuncUntilTimeOut` class and `Try` method. You can event use that class for your own purposes.

Comment: @prostynick: there is no such thing as Thread.Sleep in javascript

Comment: is there a way to access javascript global variable from Watin?
thx

Comment: Probably. Try `Eval` on your `IE` object (or frame). Unfortunately I never tried this before and can't confirm that.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using `ie.WaitUntilContainsText("my text");` ?